# Исключить из запроса timestamp

Tags: laravel

Можно ли в модели исключить из запроса created_at и updated_at , но при этом оставить возможность их создания

Comment: `оставить возможность их создания` - расшифруйте что под этим имеется в виду

Answer (score 1):

Можно в модели отключить работу с этими полями ([Timestamps](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)). Но оставить их в БД (в миграции). Тогда ты сам будешь ими управлять.

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Ещё, данные можно получать как-то так `Company::all(['id', 'name'])`. Тогда вместо запроса `SELECT * FROM ...`, будет лететь запрос `SELECT id, name FROM ...`

Comment: да, но мне кажется ТС имел ввиду еще обновление этих полей, ну иначе просто теряется смысл

Comment: я действительно не очень понял вопрос. Эти поля имеют определенное назначение. Либо их используешь так, как задумано, либо вообще убираешь. Проблем с ручным обновлением таких полей нет - просто запихиваешь в них `now()`. Как вариант, можно оставить только одно поле `created_at` и прямо в миграции прописать его заполнение (я про `->useCurrent()`).